# what should the owner address be?

Tags: gnosis-safe

we are going to deploy contract for production from Safe account.
In this case, what should the owner address be?

Should we register multiple individual addresses for our team, or should we have a new team Safe account and make only that address the owner?

Our team is trying to deploy a contract using a Safe account and would like to know what we should generally specify for the owner at this time.

So I want to make sure that our personal address is not visible from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in such cases is to use multi-sig wallets, where there are multiple owners and in order to execute transactions, it needs a certain amount of signatures. One such implementation is `https://safe.global/`.

This will not only protect your assets from attackers but also from bad actors within the team.

Answer (score 0):

Owner address could be anything that you have access to. You can either use one that you already have or create one new address and use that as owner. Generally the owner address is the one which deploy the smart contract in the blockchain. For more safety and security you can implement multisig contract in your smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give access to multiple members of your team I would suggest using `AccessControl` from OpenZeppelin instead of `Ownable` and create additional role(s).

The main reason for this change would be to give access to `transferOwnership` or to `grantRole` to as less people as you possibly can, decreasing any changes that someone will modify the owner of the contract.

With `AccessControl` you can/should also create multiple roles, so selected people can have access to selected actions.

The `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` should be solely responsible for managing roles or some very important smart contract actions, not for "daily usage"

Ofc, multi sig for `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` or any other roles is also a good idea, depending on your use case.